# R - How to use a variable created in a for loop as a column name in a data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 questions;
In first FOR, I create a variable name called "column", and in each loop I want to use this column name as a grouping variable.
In second FOR, I want to assign some values to dataframe variables by using again "column" variable. Lets say in first loop I want "df$var1 <- 999", but it does not work.
Thank you.

```
# Dataset
df <- tibble(
  var1 = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)),
  var2 = c(rep("c", 3), rep("d", 7)),
  var3 = rnorm(10)
)

# First Loop
for(x in 1:2) {
  column <- paste0("var", x)
  df2 <- df %>% group_by(column) %>% summarize(total = n())
}

# Second Loop
for(x in 1:2) {
  column <- paste0("var", x)
  df$column <- 999
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question you can wrap `!!sym()` around 'column', i.e. `!!sym(column)` will treat 'column' as a symbol and allow you to call the variable name inside a `group_by`.

For your second question, it is better to use `[` instead of `$` when assigning a variable name to data frame column. This will work, `df[[column]]`.

Comment: Both !!sym() and [[..]] works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mix the tidyverse with a for loop in the first place. It is possible, it can work perfectly fine but you have elegant solutions both in base and in tidyverse

```
# Base:
lapply(1:2, function(x) table(df[, x]))

 #It will return
[[1]]
a b 
5 5 

[[2]]
c d 
3 7
```

Which is something you can work with.
As for the second operation, it is very vaguley described. Yet, I thing you are looking something like this:

```
#Base:
for(x in 1:2) {
 df[, x] <- 999
}

#Returning
> df
# A tibble: 10 x 3
    var1  var2    var3
   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1   999   999  1.01  
 2   999   999  1.01  
 3   999   999 -0.982 
 4   999   999  0.0672
 5   999   999  2.58  
 6   999   999  1.47  
 7   999   999  0.993 
 8   999   999  1.07  
 9   999   999  0.781 
10   999   999 -1.15
```

This doesn't make much sense. If you tried to assign different values. You could do this:

```
#define values
vars <- list(999, 1:10)

for(i in 1:2) {
 df[, i] <- vars[[i]]
}

> df
# A tibble: 10 x 3
    var1  var2   var3
   <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
 1   999     1 -0.115
 2   999     2  0.349
 3   999     3 -0.675
 4   999     4 -0.725
 5   999     5 -0.634
 6   999     6 -0.748
 7   999     7  2.71 
 8   999     8 -2.09 
 9   999     9  1.45 
10   999    10  0.176
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: For the first answer with lapply; it works for this example but I am trying to use the "column" variable I create in for loop while grouping. I wanted to see how "group_by(column)" command works at each loop. For my second question, again I am trying to make "column" variable work with my dataframe. My problem was not to be able to use "df$column" while assigning a value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the final output is that you desire, but you could try the following code which should scale up if need be:

```
library(tidyverse)

##create simple count function
count_col <- function(col){
  df %>% count(!!sym(col))
}

## define your columns for counting
cols <- names(df[1:2])
## map as a list
map(cols,count_col)

## map as dataframe with separate columns
map_dfc(cols,count_col)


## change all values in specified columns
df[,cols] <- 999

## which is the same as
df[,1:2] <- 999
```